# Is there a method to consider all elements in an array when passing it through a loop like a for loop?

Tags: arrays, c

In the code below, the output ends up being 70, with a count of 4. However, the test_score 95 has a count of 5 and it should be the one that comes out on the output, but doesn't. It would seem that there is a skipping of elements in the array tes_scores[]. I can't see where I'm going wrong with the body of the function int mode( int arr[], int n ).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_SCORE 100

int mode(int arr[], int n);

int main()
{
   int test_scores[] = { 90,85,100,50,50,85,60,70,55,55,80,95,70,60,95,80,100,75,70,95,90,90,70,95,50,65,85,95,100,65 };
   int n = sizeof(test_scores) / sizeof(int);
    
   printf("Mode of the test_scores is %d\n", mode(test_scores, n));

}

int mode(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j, modes;
    int count[11] = {};
    
    int scores[11] = {100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50};
    
    modes = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(scores[j] == arr[i])
            {
                count[j] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if(count[i] > count[i + 1])
            modes = scores[i]; 
    }
    return modes;
}
```

Comment: You should describe what this is supposed to do first.

Comment: When i is 10 `count[i + 1]` is out of bounds of the array. Consider instead keeping track of the highest value by its index. Start by assuming index 0 is the highest and then check all of the other values against it updating the index when you find something higher.

Comment: `for(j = 0; j < n; j++)` Looks like the wrong bounds. `n` is the bounds of the input `arr` and not the `scores` or `count` array. Thus it is not correct to use `j` as an index for those latter arrays.

Comment: Why are you comparing `count[i]` to `count[i+1]`? There's nothing special about adjacent elements of the array. You should have a variable for the highest count, and compare with that.

Comment: As you can see, you have many problems with your `mode()` function. You need to start from scratch and think about it more clearly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's clearly trying to calculate the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of an array

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to litteraly make a for each in C, nevertheless you can use special value that specify the end of your array, for example if your score could'nt be negatives you can put a '-1' at the end to specify end of the array like a '\0' or if you make a 'type' **arr, put the last index of your array to NULL to indicate the end of it.